# Process.start no funciona en proyecto publicado C# (Publicado localmente IIS)

Tags: c#, iis

Tengo un proyecto que abre diversos archivos y carpetas de la PC, pero solo me los abre cuando este esta en "Debug", cuando lo publico, y trato de abrir un archivo de "bloc de notas", lo abre en el "administrador de tareas" pero no lo abre visualmente (Según leí es que lo abre con otro usuarios o que lo abre a nivel del servidor, lo raro es que a nivel de servidor soy yo por que lo estoy publicando localmente). Uso el siguiente codigo para abrirlo:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo()
                {
                    FileName = "file://"+@recor + drop + ruta,
                    WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal,
                    CreateNoWindow = false,
                    UseShellExecute = true,
                    Verb = "open"
                });
```

Ya le di permisos a la carpeta con los usuarios. Cree un grupo de aplicaciones, ya que cuando lo abria usando esto

```
string rutaUsuario = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile);
```

Me salia "C:\Users\DefaultAppPool" cuando la ruta no es esa.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya se que por razones de seguridad no se puede, pero el proyecto es para algo local, y no se que mas hacer para no depender estar con el Visual Studio abierto.

Comment: Que es abrir visualmente para ti, por que al final como IIS es un servicio no te va a permitir abrir nada que genere notificaciones en el escritorio, ahora si solo quieres que abra el archivo y ejecute lecturas y escrituras, puedes cambiar el usuario en el AppPol, en Administración Avanzada y asignar un usuario local, o compartir tu carpeta con todos para lectura y escritura.

Comment: @EduardoJaramilloLicea abrir visualmente es que si le digo que abra un archivo especifico de Word, yo poder ver el archivo, para poder manipularlo y no como ahora donde el archivo abre pero solo a nivel de proceso. Lo segundo no se si lo hice bien o te entendi bien, cree el grupo de aplicaciones "victor.duarte" aunque no se si sera por ahi.

Comment: Eso no te permitirá hacerlo desde un servicio en Windows, ya sea iis, ya sea servicio de Windows, para esos casos, el único lugar desde donde si puedes hacerlo es desde una aplicación de escritorio.